# Keep fixed position inside an iframe relative to the whole screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, position

Context:

- We're serving our app through an iframe inside our clients websites
- The iframe is seamless and scrolling happens only in the parent div right now.
- One of the Divs in our app has a fixed position and should always be present, no matter how much you scroll.
- Update: We deploy a javacript script next to the iframe, so we have access to the hosting page

The problem: When served inside the iframe, the fixed position Div doesn't seem to retain its fixed position relatively to the whole webpage. Meaning, when someone scrolls, the fixed div doesn't really stay fixed anymore.

Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of the app so we can put as the source of an iframe ourselves? Because if you try to iframe something like https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/ it does maintain its position on the top.

Comment: The question is whether it's possible to have an element inside an iframe stay fixed relative to the whole window. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9stbu5zr/ . Is there a way to have the inner fixed element stay in the same position as the whole window is scrolled?

Answer (score 3):

I do not see an other solution than dynamically setting the position onScroll from the outer frame, like this:

```js
    $(() => {
      $('#contentframe').ready(() => {
        const topElem = $("#top", frames['contentframe'].document);
        const topElemTopPos = topElem.offset().top;
        $(window).on('scroll', () => {
          const scrollFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
          topElem.css({ top: (scrollFromTop + topElemTopPos) + "px" });
        });    
      });
    });
```

https://codepen.io/jobe451/pen/OJWJGQX

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it unless you've got access to the hosting page as well.

**EDIT:** Given the fact you can control the hosting page too, it is sort of possible, but won't be easy or pretty :/.

It has to be via a `fixed` positioned element on the hosting page and right now I can only think of two variations on top of that:

1. Have the fixed element outside the iframe. Your script on the hosting page can create it.
2. Divide your iframe to two: one with the element which you want fixed (with `position: fixed` style) and another with everything else. Again, your script will create two iframes instead of one.

Comment: Thanks @elektronik. We deploy a .js script next to our iframe, so we do have access to the hosting page as well. Any ideas?

Comment: @STE, add a stylesheet to the hosting page (inline stylesheet or a `link` element, or event an inline style on the relevant element(s)). If all you need is a static stylesheet, then you're done! However, if you require some dynamic behaviour, you'll have to communicate between the hosting page and the hosted iframe(s). In that case, I suggest using something like [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer).

Comment: @elektronik the question is specifically about whether it's possible to maintain an element inside an iframe in a fixed position relative to the outer frame. Here's an example of the current behavior, where the inner fixed element only stays fixed relative to the iframe and not the page itself during scrolling: https://jsfiddle.net/9stbu5zr/