# Div with fixed position relative to window in a long iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, css-position, iframe-resizer

I have a widget with dynamic content in an iFrame, embedded in our client's website.
I am using iFrame resizer in order to change the height of the iFrame so to avoid scrollbars in the iFrame.

In the iFrame, I have a div that I need to be `position: fixed`, it should be visible and fixed only in the boundaries of the iFrame.

The problem is that `position: fixed` is relative to the window in which the div is in. In my case, it's the iFrame. I need it to be relative to the browser window.

I tried using the new [Intersection api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) and adding a `top-margin` to the div but even if I added 1M threshold points the div movement was flickery.

This issue is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401630/keep-fixed-position-inside-an-iframe-relative-to-the-whole-screen), except I don't have access to the parent window.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fake this behavior?

Comment: To clarify: do you want the "fixed" element to be visible outside iFrame boundaries?

Comment: @niemaszoka, Good question, I'll add it to the question itself.
No, I want the 'fixed' div to be visible only inside the iFrame.